# Numpy array * array.conj() gives different results than item by item multiply

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to multiply a 24x24 array of complex numbers by its complex conjugate. Nothing fancy, just an item-by-item multiplication.

In theory, this should result in all values having a `0j` imaginary value.  This is true if I multiply items in the array one at a time, but I get very small residual values in the imaginary parts when I just multiply the array by its `array.conj()`.

```py
Python 3.10.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Jun 23 2023, 22:34:57) [MSC v.1936 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.25.1'
>>>
>>> bob = np.array([1.1+2.2j, 3.3+4.4j])
>>> bob
array([1.1+2.2j, 3.3+4.4j])
>>>
>>> bob * bob.conj()
array([ 6.05-1.77635684e-17j, 30.25-8.17124146e-16j])
>>>
>>> bob[0] * bob[0].conj()
(6.050000000000001+0j)
>>>
```

I'm seeing this in miniconda Python 3.10, Numpy 1.25.2 on Win10

The same thing happens if I declare my variable to by complex64.

I also tried this same example in Python 3.7, Numpy 1.21.6 and got different (correct) results.

```py
Python 3.7.10 (default, Feb 26 2021, 13:06:18) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.21.6'
>>>
>>> bob = np.array([1.1+2.2j, 3.3+4.4j])
>>> bob
array([1.1+2.2j, 3.3+4.4j])
>>>
>>> bob * bob.conj()
array([ 6.05+0.j, 30.25+0.j])
>>>
>>> bob[0] * bob[0].conj()
(6.050000000000001+0j)
```

I'm not sure what to do about this or whom to report this to. Thoughts and advice are welcome.

Comment: I think you are just seeing a difference in display format (and one I can't replicate on Spyder). If you evalauate `bob[0] * bob[0].conj() == (bob * bob.conj())[0]` it will probably be `True`.

Comment: hi John, thanks for the reply.  I tried your suggestion and it comes out `False`.  I repeated my example as above for Python 3.10, Numpy 1.25 and added your statement as you wrote it, and it reports `False`. FYI, it behaves this way both in PyCharm IDE and in a Windows cmd window.

Comment: Just as a follow on, I did the same test for Python 3.9 and Numpy 1.24.4, and the array multiplication works correctly.  I'm starting to think that the problem is with Numpy 1.25.1

Comment: `-1.77635684e-17j` is essentially the same as `0j`. There is nothing wrong or unexpected in your program. Float number can never have exact precision on a computer. That's why when doing comparison among float numbers, one should always use the `isclose` function (e.g., [numpy.isclose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html), [math.isclose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose))

Comment: Hi Fanchen, thanks for your reply.  I agree with you, and frequently use `isclose` in my code.  This issue here is that I get two different answers depending on how I perform the multiplications.  Multiplying by individual items gives me *exactly* 0j in the imaginary part, but multiplying the arrays does not give me 0j.  That should not happen.